# SSH key on computer not matching the SSH key on GitHub

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I typed in the following code to check the ssh key on my computer:

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

The key it spits out does not match the key that is present on my github account. How should I proceed to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual problem you are having? There may be more than one `*.pub` file in `.ssh/`. For example, I have a `github_rsa.pub` where I store the key I use for github.

Comment: there's just one id_rsa.pub file in .ssh/

Comment: Just add it to github.

Comment: The issue was I kept getting 'permission denied (public key)' everytime I tried pulling/pushing to github and I realized the keys were different. Sorry just had a stupid moment, should have just added the key present on my computer in the first place. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The key it spits out does not match the key that is present on my github accoun

The idea of ssh key is not to reuse a public and private key pair, but to have one for each specific environment from which you are pushing to GitHub.

Once you have [generated an id_rsa (private) / id_rsa.pub (public) pair](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), public the public key on GitHub.

[image: Add ssh key]

Test if that works with a:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: Hey yeah I should have done that in the first place, before asking it here. It's fixed now. I was just confused why the keys were different since the previous key was only generated a couple of hours back and added to github.

Comment: @Fisherman great. I will leave this answer if that can help others.